# two operating systems on 2 hard drives

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive

I was wondering if anyone has done this before. I was planning on installing a second hard drive in my computer and was wondering if i could install Ubuntu seperate on that drive and not the Windows 7 drive. I would think that you should be able to unplug the Win7 hard drive and just have the separate one plugged in. I dont want to partition the Win7 drive because I will probably use up the rest of the space on it in no time at all. I was wondering if anyone has any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, indeed you can.

It is as easy as you mention: Simply unplug your Windows 7 Hard Disk Drive, plug the one where Ubuntu will reside and do the proper install. I would suggest you to also remove any other hard disk drive (if any) in order to prevent the GRUB Boot Loader from being installed somewhere else.

This process works. But you will be in the need to instruct your BIOS to boot from your main OS (if you wish auto-boot) or choose the boot drive at the startup. Certain computers allow you to do it by pressing a key then choosing the device to boot from but some of them will only let you choose if you wish to boot from DVD/HDD/USB without allowing you to choose which Hard Disk Drive is the one that you wish to boot from. Overrided by simply arranging the boot order from the BIOS.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite possible, just make sure you select your second hard drive when you install Ubuntu. Easy-peasy.